# xarray:plot missing values

Tags: python, time-series, python-xarray

I am plotting some time series that are xarray object but I have data only for May-October.
The result is this straight line:.
Do you have any idea how to remove the dates from the x-axis that are not in the dataset?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I see one block of contiguous data per year in your example, and xarray is not aware of the fact that you don't want to connect the points between the two years with lines, you could proceed like in the [docs](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.groupby.html), here for an example dataset:

```
# create basic example dataset
da = xr.DataArray(
    np.linspace(0, 1826, num=1827),
    coords=[pd.date_range("1/1/2000", "31/12/2004", freq="D")],
    dims="time",
)

# the meat of the answer: making selection of data per year easier
groups = da.groupby("time.year")
# example usage of that
for year, group in groups:    # iterate over yearly blocks
    group.plot(label=year)
```

You could also access data for 2000 via `groups[2000]`.

---

For your example as per the comment:

```py
groups = Anomalies.sel(lat=55, lon=12).groupby("time.year")
for year, group in groups:    # iterate over yearly blocks
    group.plot(label=year)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am still new in python so I do not understand how I will do that. My data are from 2000 to 2001. Should I change the linspace? Where in the code should I have my array? If I do:my_Array= xr.DataArray(
    np.linspace(0, 306, num=306),
    coords=[pd.date_range("1/5/2000", "3/09/2001", freq="D")],
    dims="time",
) then I get: ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 306 on the data but length 430 on coordinate 'time'

Comment: `da` is a placeholder example array, sorry, I should have specified that. This is the object you're most likely callying `.plot` on to get your chart in the question. You should really post your code to make debugging this easier!

Comment: I use simply Anomalies.sel(lat=55, lon=12).plot().  If I write: # create basic example dataset
Anomalies = xr.DataArray(
    np.linspace(0, 306, num=306),
    coords=[pd.date_range("1/5/2000", "30/09/2001", freq="D")],
    dims="time",
) (306 because that is how many days I have) then I get the error ValueError: conflicting sizes for dimension 'time': length 306 on the data but length 635 on coordinate 'time.

Comment: I've updated the answer. You don't need the `DataArray` line, I was just using it to show the general idea.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do you know if there is a way to delete the empty space? To connect the years from last to new value.

Comment: Can you rephrase that? I'm not sure what you'd like to do. It might be best if you ask a new question *with your code in it, please!* and add a drawing or some such visualization of what you're trying to do :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244770/discussion-between-les2004-and-dominik-stanczak).